# Need help on graphic suite of choice for iOS development

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to play around with ios development and thought of a function that I'd like to achieve but don't yet know where to begin. In short, what I want to do is being able to draw lines with touch and then compare the drawn graphics with another image by pixels. I'm wondering what graphics suite should I use for drawing and comparing image functions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quartz and Core Graphics are what you will need for pixel processing in iOS. I'm not positive if there are any open frameworks available that try to wrap some of this into friendlier usage, but i haven't used any.  Here is a link to the Quartz2d document from Apple: [Quartz 2D](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html)

As far as touch handling, there are a number of great tutorials to help with this. Try googling iphone touchesBegan.